# Disable save as & open in new tab on an image with css?

Tags: css

I know there is no point to do it, but I want to ask if it is possible to disable right click on an image with only css.

-What I want to do is to disallow naïve users from saving the images, from my WordPress website slider (MetaSlider)

Comment: You could try `pointer-events: none`.

Comment: @SLaks tried that but it doesn't seem to work with `img{pointer-events:none}`

Answer (score 8):

You can use an overlay above the image to avoid such a thing :

```css
.img-container {
  position: relative;
}

.img-container:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" />
</div>
```

This will avoid the usual save image action **but** any experienced developer will always be able to get the images (source code, inspect element, screenshot, etc).

You cannot prevent any user from saving the image whatever you will do because in all the cases the image is served with the web page and it's present in the client side.

Answer (score 7):

No, you need JavaScript.

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());
```

Comment: Don't know why this had -1 votes; this is exactly what you need, although this is added to the entire document. Might want to add it to an element instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use  `pointer-events: none;`

```css
img { 
    pointer-events: none;
}
```